# The text from Android EditText becomes garbage characters in WebView

Tags: android, html, encoding, android-edittext

I am going to get the text in an EditText and then display the text in a WebView. The following code works for ASCII characters. For non-ASCII characters, the text in WebView becomes garbage characters.

```
String input = mEditText.getText().toString();
String html = makeHTML(input); // append HTML elements and headers including MIME and ENCODING header
mWebView.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

I thought that I was doing something wrong with my HTML, so I try to display the text directly in the WebView without modify the text. However, the result was the same.

```
String input = mEditText.getText().toString();
mWebView.loadData(input, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

The `makeText()` of `Toast` which displays non-ASCII text in EditText without any problem.

Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: non-ASCII characters , can u give one or two character for testing.

Comment: The Japanese "ニュース" and Chinese "你好"

Comment: i will suggest you to check https://github.com/mayooresan/Japs-Attack-Ceylon--Android-App this project contains custom font in webview. Other way i dont knwo.

Answer (score 1):

WebView might not be able to load certain "unsafe" HTML characters. Try using:

```
String input = mEditText.getText().toString();
String html = makeHTML(input);
String encodedHtml = URLEncoder.encode(html,"UTF-8");
mWebView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

The URLEncoder.decode(encodedHtml,"UTF-8") method might also be useful.

Comment: Looks like it's a known bug. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1733 for more info and a workaround that you may be able to modify for your case. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solve the problem by using `loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, data, mimeType, encoding, historyUrl)` of `WebView`

```
mWebView.loadData(data, mimeType, encoding)

mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", data, mimeType, encoding, "")
```

seems to be same but actually does not.

In my case, `loadData()` failed to encode the characters properly and failed to load images saved in the `asset` folder.